# how to fetch core config value in observer

Tags: magento2

I am trying to fetch core_config_table values in observer but I only want to fetch fields using the below code but no success. kindly please take a look and tell me what am I missing.

```
$showTemplateHint =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general/quantity_ranges/ranges', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        // $arr = json_decode($showTemplateHint, true);
        foreach($showTemplateHint as $data){
          echo $data['price'];
        }
```

data is here under $showTemplateHint I have checked it using logger below are the data comming in this variable

> 2021-06-23T10:52:19+00:00 INFO (6):
> Info"{"_1623906869065_65":{"to_qty":"12","price":"40","plan":"Monthly
> Plan"},"_1623906912019_19":{"to_qty":"4","price":"20","plan":"Quarterly
> Plan"},"_1623906937089_89":{"to_qty":"1","price":"10","plan":"Yearly
> Plan"}}"

I only want to fetch price from this price of a respective plan

Answer (score 1):

Pleas follow below blog that will helpfull for you

https://www.magetop.com/blog/how-to-get-store-config-value-in-magento-2/

Comment: am already getting the value as i had mentioned but i want to fetch a single out of all those value

Answer (score 0):

you are getting serialized array so unserialize it.

use below code

```
 print_r(json_decode($showTemplateHint , true));
```

or

```
$showTemplateHint = unserialize($showTemplateHint ); //in magento you can use own unserialize method
var_dump($showTemplateHint );
```

hope this helps you

Comment: already tried that but its not working